# why do i need to combine two objects into one?

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
pm.mixin = function(/*Object*/ obj, /*Object...*/ props){
        if(!obj){ obj = {}; }
        for(var i=1, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++){
            mixin(obj, arguments[i]);
        }
        return obj; // Object
};
```

This a dojo mixin function http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/mixin#id2

Can anyone say me on what scenario this would be useful for me, why do i need to combine two objects into one. What is arguments.length, i don't even pass this...

Comment: The very link you've attached to your post gives you several great scenarios on `mixin` usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone say me on what scenario this would be useful for me, why do i need to combine two objects into one.

- When subclassing
- When you want to override defaults *as per the example you linked to in the question*!

> What is arguments.length

The [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object contains the arguments passed to a function.

Comment: Maybe a bit of elaboration on how the usecase of mixins differ from subclassing is in order i.e. mixins are used to extend the behavior of a class instead of specialization.